# How can I change the value between <span> tag </span> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm working on small ASP.NET MVC application which is implementing inbox for logged in user, and in case user has 2 unread messages there is icon with letter and with number which is showing how many messages are there marked as UnRead.

And this is how it looks:
[image]

And here is code that is making this looks like on a image above:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
   @if (LoggedInUser != null)
   {
           int unReadMessages = Controller.GetNumberOfUnreadMessages(LoggedInUser.LoggedInUserID);
           if (unReadMessages > 0)
           {
             <span class="badge bg-green">@unReadMessages</span>
           }
           else
           {
              <span class="badge bg-green">@unReadMessages</span>
           }

    }
```

And what I'm doing in code above is next:

Check if user is logged on system :

```
@if (LoggedInUser != null)
```

If yes, then get messagess from database ( there is count query which is counting how many messages are marked as unread because only thing I need here is number acctually to show it there when user log in).

```
int unReadMessages = Controller.GetNumberOfUnreadMessages(LoggedInUser.LoggedInUserID);
```

On another view I have list of unread messages and when I click on any of them I would like to decrease this number by one (something like `unreadMessages--;`)

This is my javascript method where I am clicking on unread messages and changing it's status into database to "Read":

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function onSelectMessage(el) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "Message/MarkMessageAsRead",
                data: { messageID: el.id }
            })
    .done(function (response) {
        $('#email-subject').text(response.subject);
        $('#email-body').text(response.body);
        $('#email-date').text(response.created);
        $('#email-sender').text(response.sender);

        var unread = el.getAttribute('data-unread');
        UpdateMessageStatus(el.id, unread);

    });
        }
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR IS DESRIBED IN CODE BELOW:
I added id to a `span` which is called `inboxMessages`
and it looked like this :

```
<span class="badge bg-green" id="inboxMessages">@unreadMessages</span>
```

After that I added this line of code in hope that will decrease my number on that letter, but unfortunatelly I failed, and I saw in console that I had value of unReadMessageCounter as NaN

var unReadMessageCounter = parseInt($('inboxMessages'));
                    --unReadMessageCounter;

SO guys I am wondering how can I get this number from my letter (in my case in this example it is : 2 value between `<span class="badge bg-green">` ), @unreadMessages in this javascript method so in ONE step I could update it on a database to mark it as read and I can decrease this number that is shown on letter ? so when user call `onSelectMessage`javascript method than I could get this integer variable that is showing my number and I could descrease it.

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any difference in the html generated based on whether there are unread messages, but here is my suggestion:

Give the span a unique ID or class value so that it can be easily selected. Something like this:

```
<span id="unreadMessageBadge" class="badge bg-green">...</span>
```

Then, you get get the contents, parse them and set a new value. Something like this:

```
var msgCount = $("#unreadMessageBadge").text();

if (msgCount !== "") {
    msgCount = parseInt(msgCount) - 1;
}
if (msgCount > 0) {
    $("#unreadMessageBadge").text(msgCount);
} else {
    $("#unreadMessageBadge").hide();
}
```